# Texture not showing when updating Three.js version

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644236/adding-night-lights-to-a-webgl-three-js-earth) hoping to add my own spin on things. I noticed the example located 
[here](http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/three.js/examples/webgl_shader_earth.html) is using a very old revision of Three.JS (49). When I changed the source file to a more up-to-date version, the texture no longer appears. See [Demo](http://globatum.com/testing/index3.php)

I've been spending a lot of time trying to figure out what depreciations occurred and I've narrowed down my search to these lines.

```
// material

uniforms = {
                sunDirection: { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0) },
            dayTexture: { type: "t", value: 0, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/world2.png" ) },
                nightTexture: { type: "t", value: 1, texture: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/world5.png" ) }
            };

            uniforms.dayTexture.texture.wrapS = uniforms.dayTexture.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;
            uniforms.nightTexture.texture.wrapS = uniforms.nightTexture.texture.wrapT = THREE.Repeat;

  material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

                uniforms: uniforms,
                vertexShader: document.getElementById( 'vertexShader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentShader' ).textContent

                } );
```

More misc stuff that probably has something to do with my problem

```
<script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        uniform sampler2D dayTexture;
        uniform sampler2D nightTexture;

        uniform vec3 sunDirection;

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vNormal;

        void main( void ) {
            vec3 dayColor = texture2D( dayTexture, vUv ).rgb;
            vec3 nightColor = texture2D( nightTexture, vUv ).rgb;

            // compute cosine sun to normal so -1 is away from sun and +1 is toward sun.
            float cosineAngleSunToNormal = dot(normalize(vNormal), sunDirection);

            // sharpen the edge beween the transition
            cosineAngleSunToNormal = clamp( cosineAngleSunToNormal * 10.0, -1.0, 1.0);

            // convert to 0 to 1 for mixing
            float mixAmount = cosineAngleSunToNormal * 0.5 + 0.5;

            // Select day or night texture based on mix.
            vec3 color = mix( nightColor, dayColor, mixAmount );

            gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );
            //gl_FragColor = vec4( mixAmount, mixAmount, mixAmount, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>

    <script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vNormal;

        void main()
        {
            vUv = uv;
            vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
            vNormal = normalMatrix * normal;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
        }

    </script>
```

I've checked the migrations docx [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration)
There isn't much on "uniforms" or "shaders" for that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Migration Wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) you referenced, it specifies a new pattern for assigning textures to uniforms as of r.51:

```
{ type: "t", value: 0, texture: map } => { type: "t", value: map }
```

So in you case, it would be

```
dayTexture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/world2.png" ) },
nightTexture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "/images/world5.png" ) }
```

three.js r.59

Comment: I made this change earlier (forgot to mention in original post) and  the entire code doesn't work.

Comment: I made the change in your code, and the textures rendered fine. This is the answer to your original question. You may have other issues.

Comment: No. I paused your code in the editor and made the change I mentioned. Both textures rendered, although the day/night was off -- but that is another issue.